# Activity transitions not animating

Tags: android, android-transitions

I've been learning about material transitions, following [this](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations/blob/master/README.md) guide.  I have a little test app where I'm trying this out.

My activity code looks like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.Slide;
import android.view.View;

public class TransitionsHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transitions_home);
    }

    public void slide(View view){
        //Create a slide object, then set it as the exit transition
        Slide slide = new Slide();
        slide.setDuration(1000);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(slide);

        startActivity(new Intent(this, SlideActivity.class));
    }
```

I have a button that calls `slide()` when it's pressed.

The problem is, it's changing to the proper activity, but it isn't animating at all.  Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `StartActivity` like this:

```
startActivity(intent,ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
```

Comment: @uestcfei So do I have to inflate the XML and call `overridePendingAnimation` and everything to be backwards-compatible?